# Lost test results in Microsoft Test manager

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, microsoft-test-manager

I have been running tests in Test Manager. This morning  I do not see some of my tests in Microsoft Test Manager under the "Test" Tab all of a sudden. I have seen them earlier :

[image]

When I look under the "Plan" Tab I see my test suites and I see below :
[image]

For test suite "4" I don't see test results (There is a blue tick mark).
For the test suite "5" I see test results(There is a play icon).

For all the test suites which have the "Play icon" I see my test results in the "Test" tab. For all the "test suites" with the "Tick mark" I do not see test resuts in the "Test" tab. Could anyone point me as to what could have happened & if there is a way to get back test results ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after much struggle found it.
The tick mark suggests the test suite has been completed. Someone marked the test suite as complete. All I had to do was change the state of the test suite from complete to in progress. There is an option on the top right side of the tool.

[image]